# Use GCP debugger but got permission error

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

I add `@google-cloud/debug-agent` on my nodejs project which is deployed on GKE.
But I got error：

```
restify listening to http://[::]:80
@google-cloud/debug-agent Failed to re-register debuggee nodejs-bot: Error: The caller does not have permission
@google-cloud/debug-agent Failed to re-register debuggee nodejs-bot: Error: The caller does not have permission
@google-cloud/debug-agent Failed to re-register debuggee nodejs-bot: Error: The caller does not have permission
@google-cloud/debug-agent Failed to re-register debuggee nodejs-bot: Error: The caller does not have permission
```

I have checked my GKE have the debug permission. I don't know why the service didn't have permission.

[image]

Here is the code I define on my index.ts

```
import * as tracer from '@google-cloud/trace-agent';
tracer.start();
import * as debug from '@google-cloud/debug-agent';
debug.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue is caused by workload identity, so I just close this feature to fix this issue.

Because I select to launch the workload identity feature. Every pod which needs to connect GCP service will need to create a service account for these pods. Otherwise, the permission will be blocked.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity

Comment: can you elaborate about how you fixed this issue with Cloud Identity, to help others?

Comment: @NachoColoma I have update more information about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by doing the following:

1 - Create a new Cluster with these permissions enabled (i.e. Cloud Debugger/ Cloud Platform 'Enabled') and with the required scopes. [[1]](https://medium.com/google-cloud/updating-google-container-engine-vm-scopes-with-zero-downtime-50bff87e5f80)

Example:

$ gcloud container clusters create example-cluster-name --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud_debugger --zone

2-  You can use the same YAML config files you used to deploy your original workloads in the new cluster. You must make sure you have the required scopes for this to work.

You can review how authentication and scopes work using [[2]](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform) [[3]](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud_debugger).

Comment: But as you could see on the image, I have already enabled the Cloud Debugger/ Cloud Platform permission on my GKE.

Comment: You have to adjust your scopes for authorization to use the debug-agent. It will take the authorization from the scope applied. This command is an example: $ gcloud container node-pools create adjust-scope \ --cluster <YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME> --zone <YOUR_ZONE> \ --num-nodes 3 \ --scopes googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write,https://…

https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/nodejs This document explains how to setup the proper scopes for this.

Comment: You will also need the following roles and permissions to be set. You can refer to https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/iam for the required ones.